# Is it possible to create a Hadoop cluster that includes Hbase, Hive and Pig on EC2 using Whirr

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig

Is it possible to create a Hadoop cluster that has Hbase, Hive and Pig along with it on Amazon EC2 using Whirr??

Answer (score 0):

According to the Whirr 0.6.0 documentation Cassandra, Hadoop, ZooKeeper, HBase, elasticsearch, Voldermort, Hama have been tested with Amazon EC2 and RackSpace Cloud Servers.

Comment: Thanks for the response Praveen..These all are provided along with the Whirr distribution, but Hive and Pig need to be configured manually.I was looking for something like that

Comment: Pig and Hive are just master-only libraries. You don't have to install this on every node. Untarring on a single host can be done without Whirr very well since decades :P